# How to recognize errors from crash logs

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

My app works great when I build and debug but when I run on its own, it crashes due to some other issues.
I have one NSObject class, one UITableView class, one UIView class , one UITableViewCell class and one NSOperation class.
Does any body have similar issues or if any one can help me out.

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release
iPhone Simulator 235, iPhone OS 4.2 (iPhone/8C134)

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x01134a67 objc_msgSend + 27
1   UIKit                           0x004ab1e2 -[UITableViewCell removeFromSuperview] + 167
2   UIKit                           0x003249d9 -[UIView dealloc] + 340
3   UIKit                           0x0032e281 -[UIScrollView dealloc] + 341
4   UIKit                           0x003661ce -[UITableView dealloc] + 1085
5   Foundation                      0x000698da __delayedPerformCleanup + 59
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00f4bbde CFRunLoopTimerInvalidate + 446
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00fb57d7 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1799
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00f11cc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00f11240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00f11161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
11  GraphicsServices                0x01874268 GSEventRunModal + 217
12  GraphicsServices                0x0187432d GSEventRun + 115
13  UIKit                           0x002fa42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
14  Time                            0x00001e08 main + 102 (main.m:14)
15  Time                        0x00001d99 start + 53
```

Comment: Post your code. You're over releasing something.

Comment: Is it possible to know which line is over releasing from the crash errors, since I cannot locate the line or the file.

Comment: @lifemoveson: You need to post your code in order to get a satisfactory answer as one cannot guess what actually might be creating the crash just by looking at the crash log.

Comment: From the menu: Do `Build` and `Build and Analyze`. Maybe Xcode will show the line to you...

Comment: Or use NSZombie to see what object is being over released. If you know, it's easier to find the bug. Google for NSZombieEnabled ...

Comment: fabian I have used Build and Build and Analyze both. No potential leak problems as whatsoever. chiefly I did use nszombie also but did not receive any warnings. dont know when it is really throwing release by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technote has the technical info on crashlogs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html

However, you are having a debugging problem, not a crashlog problem.

See tips for debugging here:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingTechniques

Interpreting crash logs takes practice.  People here see this: `removeFromSuperview` and immediately think "Aha, a clue!  this is likely a memory issue"  because removeFromSuperview will remove a view then decrement it's retain count.  if the retain count is already zero, then decrementing one more time may lead to a crash.  Thus, they think you are over releasing your `UITableViewCell`

check your UITableViewCell for alloc/init, release or autorelease...

Comment: Thanks a lot amattn. Its really pain to debug the crash when some abstract information drives you crazy. I was over auto releasing my UITableViewCell which I thought is necessary since I alloc space to it, but turned out to be not required. iOS needs to improvise its memory management with not giving so many options of memory handling.